# CSS menu bar moving out of background image

Tags: html, css

i'm working on a project for school and we have to make a webpage. Since this is my first time working on something like this i have a little problem. The problem is when i make my screen smaller in width, my menu bar moves out of my background image. You can see it here: https://r0590903.webontwerp.khleuven.be/website/html/

My html:

```css
nav {
 background: url(Images/HeaderDepot.jpg);
 height: 469px;
 width: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
 margin-top: -50px;
 display: inline-block;
 
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

ul li {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 
}

li ul {
 display: none;
}

ul li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 7px;
 text-decoration: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
 color: #000;
 background-color: #FFF;
 opacity: 0.75;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-top: 430px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="header-container">
  <header class="wrapper clearfix">
   <nav class="nav">
    <a href="HTMLDepot39HomepaginaEN.html" id="taal">EN</a>
    <a href="index.html" id="taal2">NL</a>
    <ul class="ul">
     <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="HTMLDepot39FormulierNL.html">Reserveren</a></li>
     <li><a href="HTMLDepot39FotopaginaNL.html">Galerij</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </header>
 </div>
```

I know my aside isn't right yet when you make the page smaller, but my main problem now is the menu bar.

Any ideas to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Understand what a snippet means.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `background-size:100%` from your `nav` tag.

Comment: but when i do that and i try to make it smaller, my image doesn't show full, same for when i open the site on my phone

Comment: use `background-size: cover;background-position: center;` to make your image responsive.